# Embedded document viewer - Flash

Tags: flash

We have a requirement to show documents (if we have URL for a document) within Flash. We have a need use embedded document viewer for MS Office and PDF documents. Are there any Flash controls available to acheive this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although I know that Adobe manage to include audio and video on the PDF specification it's mostly used for printed documents, and I don't think that a Flash movie qualifies as such.

On the other hand it's possible to embed a flash player on an MS Office document, with "Insert Object" method, but it's highly unused for such and I doubt that your target users will be happy to have an document, or worse an email, with Flash movies popping up.

---

Edited after clarification:

Have you tried something called [Flash Paper](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashpaper/)?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. We are looking for Flash to preview MS Office and PDF documents within a Flash and not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [scribd](http://www.scribd.com), [docstoc](http://www.docstoc.com) or [slideshare](http://www.slideshare.com).